# Does Uncharted have trophies on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, achievements, uncharted

I just played Uncharted: Drake's Fortune a couple months ago, and I noticed that it didn't have trophies. I looked online for more info, and I thought I read somewhere that they added them or something. Does it actually have trophies in some way? If so, how can I get them? I got my copy last Christmas at the same time as my PS3 Slim. I installed a rather new update with Final Fantasy XIII, and I tried loading my Uncharted game and there's no new thing in the trophies section.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to enter the game when you are logged in to the Playstation Network.

The game will ask you to update and this update will install the trophies.

But if you already played the game, you will have to play it again in order to unlock any trophy.